# Как разложить число на слагаемые в двумерный массив?

Tags: python

Пример `n = 4`

```
l = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[4]]
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: а по-русски - что именно надо сделать? а... задание конечно криво изложено, порядок слагаемых важен?

Comment: А что не так с `[2, 2]` и `[4]`?

Comment: Или убрать оба и добавить [tag:алгоритм]

Answer (score 2):

`foo(n, k)` возвращает все разбиения числа n, в которых слагаемые не больше k.
`foo(0, k)` возвращает пустой список

Находим рекуррентное соотношение, как `[i] + каждое разбиение из foo(n-i, i) для i = (0, min(n, k))`

```
def foo(n, k = None):
    if k is None:
        k = n

    if n == 0:
        return []

    result = []
    if n <= k:
        result.append([n])
    for i in range(1, 1+min(n, k)):
        for l in foo(n-i, i):
            result.append(l + [i])

    return result

print(*foo(5), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> [5]
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
> [1, 1, 1, 2]
> [1, 2, 2]
> [2, 3]
> [1, 1, 3]
> [1, 4]
> ```

То же, с list comprehension:

```
def foo(n, k = None):
    if k is None:
        k = n

    if n == 0:
        return []

    return ([[n]] if n<=k else []) + [
        l + [i]
        for i in range(1, 1+min(n, k))
        for l in foo(n-i, i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```python
n = 4

def prepare_arr(arr, n):
  arr.append(arr[-1][:-2] + [arr[-1][-2] + arr[-1][-1]] if len(arr) else [1] * n)

  if len(arr[-1]) != 1:
    prepare_arr(arr, n)

  return arr


print(prepare_arr([], n)[:-1])
```

но для получения всех слагаемых алгоритм конечно иной несколько, да и всех слагаемых чуть больше

ну или так:

```
n = 4

arr = [[1] * (n - i) + [i] for i in range(1, n)]

print(arr)
```